# Intercepting screen buffer write on xvfb

Tags: screen, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xvfb

I'm playing with R&D display hardware.

What I want to do is adapt xvfb such that it would intercept writes through the screen buffer pointer, so that I'm no longer writing to RAM but instead to my device whose hardware would interpret the write.

There are very few articles and nearly no documentation that I could find regarding the writing of low level graphics drivers.

I did look at the fb code from xorg. It seems to create a screen pointer there.

Are there only a few lowest level routines where I could intercept the pixmap to screen writes, or must I adapt a hypervisor to intercept all access to the screen map pointer?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.